# Debugging Python Script called through PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, python, debugging

I'm using PHPStorm and PyCharm as my IDE.
Is it possible to debug what's going on in the python script when called from PHP?

Here's my code:

```
$data = array('token' => $this->user_token, 'user_id' => User::getCurrentUser(),
                'archive_id' => $archive_id, 'path' => $path );

$result = shell_exec('python /mypi/Main.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
```

Ideally I would like to set a breakpoint in PyCharm and whenever the PHP script is executed, for it to allow me to debug the code.

Comment: At the very least, you can add "2>&1" to the end of the `shell_exec` string, so you can receive messages from `stderr`.